# Message count of queues bound to fanout

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

Let's assume a workflow like this:

```
                                          +-----------+
                                 +--+     |           |
                            +--->+Q1+---->+ SLOW PROC |
                            |    +--+     |           |
                            |             +-----------+
+-----------+               |             +-----------+
|           |   +------+    |    +--+     |           |
| FAST PROC +---+FANOUT+--->---->+Q2+-----> SLOW PROC |
|           |   +------+    |    +--+     |           |
+-----------+               |             +-----------+
                            |             +-----------+
                            |    +--+     |           |
                            +---->Q3+---->+ SLOW PROC |
                                 +--+     |           |
                                          +-----------+
```

The fast process (publisher) is fed by an infinite source. I need to ensure that it doesn't fill Q1..Q3 faster than the slow processes (consumer) can handle it.

I could achieve that by setting a limit on Q1..Q3 and republish the messages if it fails.

But according to the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html):

> The message will still be published to all other queues which can enqueue it.

Thats a problem because i need every message delivered to each consumer only once. But how can I republish to only those consumers who couldn't it in the first time?

Is there any way to accomplish a soft limit smaller than the actual limit and get a notification before the hard limit is reached? That way fast proc could backoff but still having all messages delivered.

Or even better: Is it possible to get the message count of all bound queues? (Using Python/Pika)

Comment: Update: At the moment it looks like [Flow Control](https://www.rabbitmq.com/flow-control.html) would take care of this

Comment: Flow control is not going to work here, as it's designed for cases where the delivery to the queue is not managed, while your problem is delivery to the consumers. Could you clarify a bit your case still? Because the only way I can understand it is that the producer would produce fast, but by burst. And you'd hope for the volume produced during a longer period to be similar to the volume consumed in the same period.

Comment: Hey Oliver, the producer is a crawler and the consumers are mining processes. Downloading pages is much faster than analysing them. I want to throttle the crawler to a rate the miners can handle but as they change over time this rate is not fixed (and hence cannot be pre-configured). So the main question is how does the crawler know that it is too fast and should backoff a little.

Comment: Hi Raphael. Thanks for clarifying your use case. I haven't seen (yet) a way to handle the case as you wish to. Typically I'd expect the "solution" recommended would be to increase the consumers per queue so that they can keep up with the producer. That said, how much logic would you be willing to put in the producer side? It could for example keep track of the queues size and pause when its too large?

Comment: Hi Oliver. I think putting the logic into the producer would be the best I could do. Theoretically I could use the [Management API](https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/) to get the size of Q1..Q3. Somehow this feels a bit dirty to me. What do you think?

Comment: I understand your feeling, but don't see a better approach. The other possibility would be kind of similar, putting information in some of the message headers to ensure that at regular intervals the consumers notify they have reached till there, and otherwise the producer waits (like [reply-to](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html)) model. As you can see from the description, it is even more clunky than checking the management api for the queues length

Comment: then that's the way I'm going to do it :) Thanks a lot for your help. I very much appreciate it!